# Create hundreds of complex geometric shapes with cubes, triangles and tetrahedra

Tags: 3d, cad, geometry

I'm going to investigate the *[marching cubes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marching_cubes)* algorithm. For that, I have to draw and keep track of `256` - actually `128` due to symmetry - geometric configurations like below. I should be able to assign index/ID to nodes and edges.

[image: Shapes]

## Question

Drawing and keeping track of all the `128` configurations by hand is a daunting task.

What are the best desktop or mobile applications to help me do that? One application in my mind is [FreeCAD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeCAD). But I haven't tried it yet. I'm not sure.

I prefer applications which can be run on Linux. I'm using openSUSE Leap.

## Update

The development is being done here that looks promising: https://github.com/Megidd/tetrahedron-table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One program meeting your Linux requirement is OpenSCAD, which is three dimensional modeling software using text based code.

If your abilities extend to creating such code, you'll find that [OpenSCAD](https://openscad.org/) supports vectors, arrays, loops, conditionals, etc. in such a manner to facilitate repetitive creation.

As I am not conversant with the information contained in the link regarding marching cubes, I cannot be confident that this is a certain solution.

OpenSCAD primarily creates STL files which are triangular surfaces and may negate your objective. Alternatively, one can define polygons and polyhedral solids by specifying points in three-space. These points can be created in the code in the form of lists and defined as such for easier management.

The shaded/colored areas in your image appear to be triangles of this sort, hence my suggestion.

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to try OpenSCAD.

Comment: I tried OpenSCAD as mentioned here: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/87009/12269 It might be really helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

This OpenSCAD script breaks down a cube into 6 tetrahedra.

This helped: https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/90011/67985

This might be an indication that OpenSCAD might be useful for investigating complex geometric shapes.

[image: Screenshot]

```
// Define the size of the cube
size = 50;

// Define the transparency of the tetrahedra
alpha = 0.5;

// Define the colors of the tetrahedra
colors = [
    [1, 0, 0, alpha],  // red
    [0, 1, 0, alpha],  // green
    [0, 0, 1, alpha],  // blue
    [1, 1, 0, alpha],  // yellow
    [1, 0, 1, alpha],  // magenta
    [0, 1, 1, alpha]   // cyan
];

// Define the vertices of the cube
cube_vertices = [
    [0, 0, 0],
    [size, 0, 0],
    [size, size, 0],
    [0, size, 0],
    [0, 0, size],
    [size, 0, size],
    [size, size, size],
    [0, size, size]
];

tetrahedron_indices = [
    [0, 4, 7, 6],
    [0, 3, 7, 6],
    [0, 4, 5, 6],
    [0, 1, 5, 6],
    [0, 3, 2, 6],
    [0, 1, 2, 6],
];

// Define the tetrahedra by selecting vertices from the cube
for (i = [0:5]) {
    // Define the indices of the vertices for the tetrahedron
    vertex_indices = tetrahedron_indices[i];
    
    echo("Tetrahedron ", i, ": ", vertex_indices);
    
    // Define the vertices of the tetrahedron
    tetrahedron_vertices = [
        cube_vertices[vertex_indices[0]],
        cube_vertices[vertex_indices[1]],
        cube_vertices[vertex_indices[2]],
        cube_vertices[vertex_indices[3]]
    ];
    
    // Color the tetrahedron with the specified color
    color(colors[i]) polyhedron(points=tetrahedron_vertices, faces=[[0, 1, 2], [0, 2, 3], [0, 3, 1], [1, 2, 3]]);
}
```